# event capture by multiple absolute elements

Tags: javascript, html, events, dom-events

I have multiple divs receiving mouse-mouse event like below, the divs overlapped in some area. If mouse pointer is on the overlapped area I need both of the events to fire (ie. printing blue and red), currently it only print red.

```
  <div style="border: solid 1px blue;width:100px;height:100px;
              position:absolute;top: 50px;left:50px;"
       onMouseMove="console.log('blue');">
  </div>

  <div style="border: solid 1px red;width:100px;height:100px;
              position:absolute;top: 20px;left:20px;"
       onMouseMove="console.log('red');">
  </div>
```

code: https://jsfiddle.net/0r1sjzgx/

Comment: I'm afraid that seems impossible by definition. The event is handled by one handler and that's it. What you CAN do is wrap those elements in another element and set the listener to the wrapping element's mousemove, then have its handler do two different things on different conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can definitely try something like this.

```js
function checkOverlap(object) {
  var div1 = document.getElementById("myDiv1");
  //positions of div1
  var rect1 = div1.getBoundingClientRect();

  var div2 = document.getElementById("myDiv2");
  var rect2 = div2.getBoundingClientRect();

  //X and Y co-ordinate of mouse
  var x = event.clientX;
  var y = event.clientY;

  if ((x > rect2.left) && (y > rect2.top)) {
    console.log('happy');
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv2" style="border: solid 1px blue;width:100px;height:100px;
    position:absolute;top: 50px;left:50px;">
</div>

<div id="myDiv1" style="border: solid 1px red;width:100px;height:100px;
    position:absolute;top: 20px;left:20px;  z-index: 1;" onMouseMove="checkOverlap();">
</div>
```

Here "happy" will print if you hover on the overlapping part only.